# Android App displays login screen at first by default (Google auto sign in feature in embedded in the app)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I tried using conditional operator to check whether the user is logged in or not and according set the home to first screen or login screen but the problem is whenever I start my app it shows the login screen first for few milliseconds before moving to the first screen ! Can someone suggest a fix!

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserInfo();
  }

  Future getUserInfo() async {
    await getUser();
    setState(() {});
    print(uid);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Login',

      home:
      (uid != null && authSignedIn != false) ? FirstScreen() : LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

I have added the getuser() function below:-

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

bool authSignedIn;
String uid;
String name;
String imageUrl;
Future getUser() async {
  // Initialize Firebase
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  bool authSignedIn = prefs.getBool('auth') ?? false;

  final User user = _auth.currentUser;

  if (authSignedIn == true) {
    if (user != null) {
      uid = user.uid;
      name = user.displayName;

      imageUrl = user.photoURL;
    }
  }
}

Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {
  // Initialize Firebase
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final User user = userCredential.user;

  if (user != null) {
    // Checking if email and name is null
    assert(user.uid != null);
    assert(user.email != null);
    assert(user.displayName != null);
    assert(user.photoURL != null);

    uid = user.uid;
    name = user.displayName;

    imageUrl = user.photoURL;

    assert(!user.isAnonymous);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

    final User currentUser = _auth.currentUser;
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('auth', true);

    return 'Google sign in successful, User UID: ${user.uid}';
  }

  return null;
}

void signOutGoogle() async {
  await googleSignIn.signOut();
  await _auth.signOut();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setBool('auth', false);

  uid = null;
  name = null;

  imageUrl = null;

  print("User signed out of Google account");
}
```

Comment: I faced a similar condition a few months ago and the solution I came up with was that I added a splash screen in my app. So whenever, the app is launched, the splash screen starts and in that, I did the processing of checking if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: The code here is incomplete.  Please edit the question to show `getUser`.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have added the required code !

Comment: You'll have to figure out what you want to display until the current user is available.  Since it's an asynchronous API, you can expect to wait any amount of time for it to become available.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use routing. There really good tutorials about routing and navigation in flutter on youtube. Also I put here a little example for routing.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Code Sample for Navigator',
      // MaterialApp contains our top-level Navigator
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (BuildContext context) => HomePage(),
        '/signup': (BuildContext context) => SignUpPage(),
      },
    );
  }
```